# Numpy: Add something before array

Tags: numpy

When I print a Numpy array,I want to add something before array like this:

G1: first row

G2: second row

G3: Third row

What i have done is like this,but the result is not satisfy what I want.

```
c = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
for i in range(1,3):
    for row in c:
        print('G'+str(i))
        print(row)
```

Result:

```
G1
[0 1 2]
G1
[3 4 5]
G1
[6 7 8]
G2
[0 1 2]
G2
[3 4 5]
G2
[6 7 8]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
for i, row in enumerate(c):
    print('G' + str(i+1) + ': ' + str(row))
```

Result:

```
G1: [0 1 2]
G2: [3 4 5]
G3: [6 7 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

This works as I think you want.

```py
import numpy as np
c = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
for i in range(c.shape[0]):
    print(f'G{i+1}: {c[i]}')
```

Result:

```
G1: [0 1 2]
G2: [3 4 5]
G3: [6 7 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

just a little tweak on your code :

```
c = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
for i in range(1,3):
    for row in c:
        print('G'+str(i), end=' ')
        print(row)
```

Comment: yeah my mistake. you should use enumerate. mentioned in next answer